# Evaluate $ \int_2^{10} \sqrt{1+\frac{0.6}{x^2}}\,dx $

Tags: integration

I have a tough integral I am attempting to evaluate. I know it looks simple but it is quite complex. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

I need to evaluate
$$
\int_2^{10} \sqrt{1+\frac{0.6}{x^2}}\,dx
$$

A general solution for 
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}\,dx
$$
would be ideal.

Comment: This is what Wolfram Alpha is for. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1+%2B+a%2Fx%5E2)+integral

Comment: wolfram's answer is not very good there, it doesn't want to show me the workings without an upgrade, and the term it comes up with is very complicated.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}} \, dx &= \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{x} \, dx
\end{align*}
Put $x = a\tan\theta$. The integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{a\sec^3\theta}{\tan\theta} d\theta &= a\int\frac{1}{\sin\theta\cos^2\theta}d\theta \\
&= a\int \frac{\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta}{\sin\theta\cos^2\theta}d\theta \\
&=a\int \sec\theta \tan\theta\, d\theta + a\int \mathrm{cosec}\, \theta \, d\theta\\
&= a\left(\sec\theta + \log(\mathrm{cosec}\, \theta -\cot\theta)\right)
\end{align*}
One can evaluate the definite integral using this.

We can also use the substitution $x^2+a^2 = t^2$. We have $x dx = t dt$ and the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{t^2}{t^2-a^2} dt &= \int dt + a^2\int\frac{dt}{t^2-a^2} \\
&= t + \frac{a}{2}\log\left|\frac{t-a}{t+a}\right|
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts
$$ \int\frac{\sqrt{1+z^2}}{z^2}\,dz = C-\frac{\sqrt{1+z^2}}{z}+\text{arcsinh}(z) \tag{1}$$
and the substitution $x=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{z}$ brings your integral into the LHS of $(1)$ multiplied by $\sqrt{a}$.